# Multiple/Dependent Sub-Queries

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am currently working within SQL Workbench/J and Redshift. I am still learning a bit, and have a question around creating a sub-query that is dependent upon another sub-query result. In the below example, a sub-query has been implemented in order to produce the mean of multiple records grouped upon a unique symbol. I am then using the mean in the primary query to calculate additional values (USD/UCL/LCL). However, I need to add a where clause on these aggregate values, which I cannot do. How would I implement another layer of sub-query to pre-calculate the UCL/LCL due to it being dependent on the first subquery to generate? I have tried adding it to the first sub-query, but have been unsuccessful. I appreciate the help in advance, as I am just learning.

```
select 
    symbol, 
    mean,
    avg(volume) as volume,
    (mean * avg(volume) * 0.001) as USD,
    STDV,
    (MEAN + STDV * 3) as UCL,
    (MEAN - STDV * 3) as LCL,
    sum((high > ucl)::int) as ucltest,
    sum((low < lcl)::int) as lcltest
from 
    (select 
         h.*,
         avg(close) over (partition by symbol) as mean,
         cast(stddev_samp(close) over (partition by symbol) as dec(14,2)) as STDV
     from 
         historical h) 
group by 
    symbol, mean, STDV;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another layer of query but there are issues.  The first thing is you need to remember that you have the mean (and stdv) for each value of symbol repeated for each row coming out of the sub query.  This is why you need the group by on these to get down to a single value per symbol.  This is one way to do it but since these are all correlated it is better to use an aggregate function like MIN(MEAN) as MEAN.  This also leads to confusion as there are two values with the name MEAN.

Now the real issue is that you are trying to use ucl and lcl in an aggregate function.  These are local to this level of the query so you are seeing an error.  You just need to repeat the calculation for these values.  Like this (untested):

```
select 
    symbol, 
    min(lmean) as mean,
    avg(volume) as volume,
    (min(lmean) * avg(volume) * 0.001) as USD,
    min(LSTDV) as STDV,
    min(LMEAN + LSTDV * 3) as UCL,
    min(LMEAN - LSTDV * 3) as LCL,
    sum((high > (LMEAN + LSTDV * 3))::int) as ucltest,
    sum((low < (LMEAN - LSTDV * 3))::int) as lcltest
from 
    (select 
         h.*,
         avg(close) over (partition by symbol) as lmean,
         cast(stddev_samp(close) over (partition by symbol) as dec(14,2)) as LSTDV
     from 
         historical h) 
group by 
    symbol
having 
    lcltest = 0 and ucltest = 0; --Having clause excludes any groups with either lcltest or ucltest not equal to 0
```

Comment: The problem with the example provided is that it lack the where clause - which is why I am trying to create the values in a sub-query. I need where lcltest = 0 and ucltest = 0. I cannot add this clause due to both being aggregate values in the primary query.

Comment: So you want to only produce rows when lcltest = 0 and ucltest = 0 for a given symbol group?  That's a HAVING clause.  Think of HAVING as as last minute WHERE clause on the grouped data.  I'm update my answer to include this so you can see how this is done.